# Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress, error-handling

I am trying to add the code on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_elements

but it give me an error on the js:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementsByClassName')
at main.js?ver=5.8.2:35

I am trying to add it on: https://nuovosito.lealternative.net/test-browser-4/

It seems to work fine, except that it can't find an active class to the current button.

EDIT:

here the part of code that give error:

```
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("bottone");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code into a snippet. If that link you provided were to go down, then this question cannot be answered and wouldn't be of value to others. However based on the error message, it's saying whatever is calling `getElementsByClassName` is `null`. Whether that's `document. getElementsByClassName` or `someElement.getElementsByClassName`, that then means `document` or `someElement` is `null` and only Elements can use `.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the script is executing before `#myBtnContainer` has loaded onto the page. This can be fixed by placing your `<script>` tag for `main.js` in your `<body>` below all of the other HTML content, or adding the `defer` tag like so:

```
<script src='https://nuovosito.lealternative.net/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/assets/js/main.js?ver=5.8.2' id='js-file-js' defer></script>
```

Another way to fix it would be to wrap all of your scripts in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener, which will make the things inside only execute after all HTML elements are loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // put your whole script here
});
```